# header file include another header file generate redefinition

Tags: c, keil

Does the header file couldn't include another header file in C?

I download the code from Nuvoton website, for Keil C51 project, use the UART sample code, just add the file "EasyTransfer.h" and include "Typedef.h", the result shows lots of error message below.

\N79E85x_Sample_Code_V1.0.8(1)\Include\Typedef.h(1): error C231: 'BIT': redefinition
\N79E85x_Sample_Code_V1.0.8(1)\Include\Typedef.h(2): error C231: 'UINT8': redefinition
\N79E85x_Sample_Code_V1.0.8(1)\Include\Typedef.h(3): error C231: 'UINT16': redefinition
\N79E85x_Sample_Code_V1.0.8(1)\Include\Typedef.h(4): error C141: syntax error near 'UINT32'
\N79E85x_Sample_Code_V1.0.8(1)\Include\Typedef.h(6): error C231: 'uint8_t': redefinition
\N79E85x_Sample_Code_V1.0.8(1)\Include\Typedef.h(7): error C231: 'uint16_t': redefinition
\N79E85x_Sample_Code_V1.0.8(1)\Include\Typedef.h(8): error C141: syntax error near 'uint32_t'

The "EasyTransfer.h" is simple, just few of lines

```
#ifndef EasyTransfer_h
#define EasyTransfer_h
#include "Typedef.h"
uint8_t * address;  //address of struct    
#endif
```

The following is the main code and [source link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6RzrpHF18PGeFF0WWdTTHlFMU0/view?usp=sharing), I think it could be helpful to understand my question.

```
#define Uart_Port_Sel   0x00

#include <stdio.h>
#include "N79E85x.h"
#include "Typedef.h"
#include "Define.h"
#include "Common.h"
#include "Delay.h"
#include "Version.h"
#include "EasyTransfer.h"
UINT8 u8Uart_Data;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void main (void)
{
    AUXR1 |= Uart_Port_Sel;             // Select P10/P11 as UART pin(default)

    InitialUART0_Timer1(9600);          // 9600 Baud Rate @ 11.0592MHz
    Show_Version_Number_To_PC();
    ES = 1;                             // Enable serial interrupt
    EA = 1;                             // Enable global interrupt

    while(1);                           // Endless
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void UART_ISR(void) interrupt 4
{
    if (RI == 1)
    {                                   // If reception occur
        RI = 1;                         // Clear reception flag for next reception
        u8Uart_Data = SBUF;             // Read receive data
        SBUF = u8Uart_Data;             // Send back same data on UART
    }
    else TI = 0;                        // If emission occur
                                        // Clear emission flag for next emission
}
```

Comment: Usually when you get redefinition errors, the compiler will also tell you where the first definition was. Is the error message you show *complete*? Unedited?

Comment: Also, does the `Typedef.h` header file have a header include guard? And what does it look like? Posting unrelated source and headers doesn't make much sense, it's the `Typedef.h` header file we need to see,

Comment: Is the include guard is #ifndef ... #define ...?

Comment: Yes. The include guard for `EasyTransfer.h` is the `EasyTransfer_h` stuff. `Typedef.h` should have a similar but different one (e.g. `Typedef_h`)

Comment: I have add  the include guard, and the error message shows different...*** ERROR L104: MULTIPLE PUBLIC DEFINITIONS
    SYMBOL:  ADDRESS
    MODULE:  .\Objects\EasyTransfer.obj (EASYTRANSFER)

Comment: It seems i couldn't create EasyTransfer.c in my project, if I use the variable uint8_t * address in EasyTransfer.c, it shows the MULTIPLE PUBLIC DEFINITIONS SYMBOL...

Comment: That last bit might be because you *define* the variable `address` in the header file. Meaning all source files you include `EasyTransfer.h` in will have that definition. It doesn't help us answering your *original* question though, about the errors you show. For that we need more information, like the `Typedef.h` header file. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Oh, I fix it, it really the include guard. Thanks all :-)

Comment: And the variable uint8_t * address should add extern !

Comment: Just wondering what is in `Define.h`?

Comment: The `Typedef.h` header contains a sequence of lines like: `typedef bit BIT;` and `typedef unsigned char UINT8;` with no header guards.  Unless you use a C11 compiler, that will generate errors when reincluded.  The `Define.h` header contains a sequence of macro definitions such as: `#define TBYTE0(v1) ((UINT8)((v1)&0xFF))` and `#define SET_BIT0 0x01`.  The header has no header guard macros, but reincluding the header ends up with 'benign redefinition' of the macros, so there's no error.

Comment: This is basically now a 'trivial typo' (though "doesn't work and missing MCVE ([MCVE])" could also be a valid close reason).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not include Typedef.h multiple times since there is no header include guard in Typedef.h.

Your main source includes Typedef.h and EasyTransfer.h at the same time, this causes redefinition errors because EasyTransfer.h includes Typedef.h too. Just like your main source includes Typedef.h twice, and WITHOUT header include guard!

I suggest you just remove the #include "Typedef.h" line from your main source file. Or add header include guard in Typedef.h if you can.